# Is it possible to connect machine to esxi Virtual Machine directly

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have one server and i want to install VMs on that.

Now i want to use one of VM as my main OS and i want that when i turn on second computer then that VM OS opens up.

One way is to use remote desktop connection but for that i need to install OS on Second computer. Is there any way to directly link Second computer to VM on Server so that i don't have to install OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no. There is no way to get hardware DMA from a virtual machine in a way that would allow you to interact directly with that VM from an external machine without any software.

On the second machine, however, it would be possible to use a stripped-down thin client OS (like Windows FLP, Windows CE, LTSP etc) which would emulate a "thin client" and then connect to the VM over RDP. This also allows you more flexibility in the kind of presentation server software you wish to use (X, RDP, Citrix, VNC, Tarentella etc.)

Comment: is it possible to use any OS with no GUI like linux , window etc so that i can run RDP from command line. Basically i need no GUI in that OS and i can use VM

Comment: I suppose it would be possible if you could find a RDP client that uses framebuffer rather than X-Windows, but I don't see the point: it is easy as pie to run a minimal windowing system like fluxbox and use the rdesktop in the init script: this is the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: How can i install fluxball . Can you please explain the steps i need to follow , e,g first i nned to install linux and then fluxball or it is ready made OS

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a PC\server\host with a Hypervisor running a number of VM's and also have one of those VM's act as the console operating system for that host. This is the sort of thing that a Type-1 Client Hypervisor is supposed to deliver.

Unfortunately there aren't any mature mainstream examples yet but Citrix can now deliver a Type 1 Client Hypervisor with the [XenClient component](http://community.citrix.com/display/ocb/2010/05/18/Explaining+XenClient+to+Our+Friends+at+VMware) of their XenDesktop solution. VMware don't have one despite a lot of rumours over the years, and recently they have indicated they don't have anything ready to release. Some other companies ([like Virtual Computer with their NXTop](http://simonbramfitt.com/2010/08/virtual_computer_spoils_vmwares_day.html) product) can also do this but they are not very well known.

In any case you are looking for a product that is described as a bare metal or **type 1 client hypervisor**, and sometimes it's called a **bare metal desktop hypervisor**. Common virtualization solutions generally fall into the Type 2 hypervisor bucket (VMware Workstation, Fusion, Parallels, VMware Server, Virtualbox..) or the Type 1 server hypervisor bucket (VMware ESX\ESXi, HyperV, Xen). Even if you plan to run a Server OS on this system what you describe requires a Client Hypervisor, at least as far as the major virtualization vendors use of the terminology is concerned.

The second thing you want to do is have a minimally configured other PC that automatically connects to a VM instance on the first system when it boots. There are a ton of solutions for this - search for Thin Client LiveCD for a bunch of examples e.g. [ThinStation](http://www.thinstation.org/).